# Abnormal behaviour of layout toggle led indicator

Tags: keyboard-layout

I have installed Ubuntu trusty in my desktop PC. I use Latin (English US) and Greek keyboard layout.

I have changed the default key-combination (Super+space) to (Shift+Alt L) in order to toggle between the two.

My problem is this:

I have the num lock on and the corresponding LED is on.
When I press the layout toggle combination (Shift+Alt L) the layout changes **and** the num LED turns off. I can still type numbers though by the numerical pad.
When I toggle again the layout changes, but the num LED keeps still off.
This weird behaviour shows even if I change the combination to the initial default (Super+space).

At this point, I must  inform you that the dconf setting (org>gnome>desktop>applications.input-sources>xkb-options) is ['grp:alt_shift_toggle', 'grp_led:scroll'], meaning that the scroll lock should be turned on - off when I toggle layouts. I must also point out that the shown parameter 'grp:alt_shift_toggle' keeps the same even when I have changed the key compbination to default (Super+space).

Any ideas how to make it work as it should (scroll lock LED on) when Gr layout is used?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: launchpad has a bugreport for this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1247668
There are one possible solution, but it does not work for me.

Comment: The behavior in the bug 1247668 is a little different of what i describe. In my case, toggling the keyboard (En to Gr) turns off the NUM led, but digits work well! I press 4 and I see "4", I press 7 and I see "7".